# Windows 10 UWP App: Easiest place to upload a large file to?

Tags: c#, file-upload, uwp, windows-10

If a user has a problem with our UWP app that I can't reproduce, I want to give the user a button, so she can upload the sqlite database to somewhere where I can access it. The zipped database could be up to 160 MB.

My question is where is the easiest place to upload a large file to using UWP. Pushbullet, OneDrive, Dropbox? Or I could FTP it to somewhere (am about to try this out [FtpClient](https://github.com/kiewic/FtpClient)). I've noticed that [Chilkat](https://www.example-code.com/csharp_winrt/dropbox_file_stream_upload.asp) can help with this, but it's not free.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says questions asking us to recommend or find off-site resources are off-topic here.

Comment: @KenWhite I'm not asking which product is best. I'm asking which is easier to upload files to using UWP.

Comment: *Which service is easier* is a recommendation, and in addition is primarily opinion-based, both of which make it off topic here. Test them and decide which best suits your needs.

Comment: @GailFoad for me i prefere to use ftpclient with BackgroundTransfer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is where is the easiest place to upload a large file to using UWP.

The better way is using `OneDrive` to upload  sqlite database. It has enough memory capacity, And you could easily use `OneDrive` API in the uwp app. This is [OneDrive Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/services/onedrive) you could refer.
And this is code [sample](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp/SamplePages/OneDrive%20Service).